# Parse loading Image into UIImageView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, parse-platform

Here is the code for the data I am passing on to the scene with the image:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    rowNo = indexPath.row;
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:currentUser.username];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        _photo = [objects objectAtIndex:rowNo];
    }];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImageCloseup" sender:self];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    ImageCloseupViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    destination.photoObject = _photo;
}
```

And here is the code which loads the image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFFile *p = [_photoObject objectForKey:@"photo"];
   [p getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
       if(!error){
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
           [_imageView setImage:image];
       }
   }];
```

For some reason, the image is not loading, why is this is so? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    _photo = [objects objectAtIndex:rowNo];
}];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImageCloseup" sender:self];
```

Needs to be:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    _photo = [objects objectAtIndex:rowNo];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImageCloseup" sender:self];
}];
```

Because:

```
// Runs 1st - executes in background thread stores block, then runs block once it's done
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // Runs 3rd - already segued at this point
    _photo = [objects objectAtIndex:rowNo];
}];

// Runs 2nd - starts segue
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImageCloseup" sender:self];
```

However, this seems like there's an overall problem with your design pattern.  If you already have access to objects, you shouldn't have to requery the entire database each time. Do you have a reference to the array populating the tableView?  If so, something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    rowNo = indexPath.row;
    _photo = yourDataArray[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImageCloseup" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: cool, this works. I'm trying to accept your answer, but it keeps saying "accept in one minute" lol

Comment: No problem @user3140562  - I made an update at the bottom that you should look at that I think will help you in the long run.  Good luck with the rest of your project!